# Heroku Node.JS errors

Tags: node.js, heroku

Heroku gives me this error, after I deploy the node.js app of mine. Do you have any idea what is error message means? Thank you!

```
2013-01-14T22:50:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-01-14T22:50:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:252
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw new Error(msg);
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Router.route.Route.sensitive (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:252:11)
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Router.route (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:248:13)
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Router.methods.forEach.Router.(anonymous function) [as get] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:16)
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.methods.forEach.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:411:26)
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Routes.self.init (/app/routes.js:23:9)
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:42:8)
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
2013-01-14T22:50:37+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2013-01-14T22:50:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-01-14T22:50:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking your /app/routes.js file, there will be a route that doesn't have two parameters. Try commenting out around lines 23.

Or isn't being defined properly, but this issue shouldn't be related to Heroku, and it should throw an error when you boot node app.js locally *shrug*

Hope you managed to sort it!

Comment: Or, if you are silly like me, you put the name of a function in but never got around to writing the function! (Confusing when you come back to a side project 6 months later!)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that's your app's problem and not a issue related to Heroku.

You should try to running the project locally, and figure out the problems.

Check your `app/routes.js' file.